# C++: Access certain element in list of vectors

Tags: c++, list, vector

I have list of vectors:

```
list< vector<int> > myList;
```

The structure of this list:

```
({1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, ...)
```

I want to get a certain element by his positions. For example, `getFromList(myList, 0, 2)` will return `3`. I tried this, but it does not work:

```
int getFromList(list< vector<int> > myList, int i, int j) 
{
    int ki = 0, kj = 0, num;
    for (list<vector<int>>::iterator it1 = myList.begin(); it1 != myList.end(); ++it1) {
        vector<int>::iterator it2;
        ki++;
        for (it2 = (*it1).begin(); it2 != (*it1).end(); ++it2) {
            kj++;
            if (ki == i && kj == j) {
                num = (*it2);
            }
        }
    }

    return num;
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of errors if I use your command, Cássio Renan. The first error: `Error 28 error C2227: left of '->at' must point to class/struct/union/generic type`

Comment: @CássioRenan `list` iterator returned by `begin()` is a bidirectional iterator. You are not allowed to use `operator+` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>


int getFromList( const std::list<std::vector<int>> &myList, size_t i, size_t j )
{
    if ( !( i < myList.size() ) ) throw std::out_of_range( "The frst index is out of the range" );

    auto it = std::next( myList.begin(), i );

    if ( !( j < it->size() ) ) throw std::out_of_range( "The second index is out of the range" );

    return it->operator []( j );
}    

int main()
{
    std::list<std::vector<int>> myList = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6, 7 }, { 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 } };

    std::cout << "myList[" << 2 << "][" << 3 << "] = " << getFromList( myList, 2, 3 ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
myList[2][3] = 11
```

Pay attention that the first parameter of the function is const reference.

As for your function then it has undefined behaviour when one of the indices is out of the valid range because the function returns uninitialized value of variable `num`.

Comment: Is there any reason that you throw your own exception here for the check on the second index instead of relying on the bounds checking that `vector::at` would do?

Comment: @SimonGibbons It is a bad idea when two throws are inconsistent with each other.  One issues a user-defined clear message and other issues a system message.

Answer (score 3):

The solution that Cássio provided in the comments won't work as you cannot randomly access elements of a `list`

Instead you can use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) defined in the header `<iterator>` to do this like so:

```
return std::next(myList.begin(), i)->at(j);
```

Note that this method doesn't do any bounds checking on the size of the list that you pass in. Before returning this you should check that `i` is a valid index.

Answer (score 0):

I found some decision on my own:

```
int getFromList(list< vector<int> > myList, int i, int j) 
{
    list<vector<int>>::iterator iter = myList.begin();
    advance(iter, i);
    vector<int> x = (*iter);

    return x[j];
}
```

Comment: It is a not a good decision because you 1) pass the list by value; 2) you do not check valid ranges; 3) you create a vector inside the function.

Comment: Ok, Vlad. In this case it's better to use decision provided by you or Simon.

Comment: His solution has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I understood you and edited my comment. Thanks and hello from Russia.